# Adding restrictions to validate json data send to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

So I've been creating a Rails API (A school project) and everything works fine, but now I want to add some restrictions to the POST endpoint.
So here is my create endpoint when I'm going to foo.com/api/v1/slogans :

```
def create
  slogan = Slogan.new(slogan_params)
  if(slogan.save)
    render json: {
      status: 'SUCCESS',
      message: 'Saved slogan',
      data: slogan
    }, status: :ok
  else 
    render json: {
      status: 'ERROR',
      message: 'Slogan not saved',
      data: slogan.error
    }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

And these are my slogan_params :

```
private def slogan_params
  params.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :slogan)
end
```

Now how do I add restrictions to this, for example a character limit? I've already added one on my front end but I want to be sure that even if the front end is manipulated that the data don't get submitted if valid.

I thought about adding something in `def create` but not sure if that is the way to do it.

Comment: Usually, you validate on saving the record with [validators](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate).

Comment: If you're interested in the different predefined validations check out the Rails guide: [Active Record Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```rb
class Slogan < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

And in controller you can do

```rb
def create
  slogan = Slogan.new(slogan_params)
  if slogan.valid?
    slogan.save
    render json: {
      status: 'SUCCESS',
      message: 'Saved slogan',
      data: slogan
    }, status: :ok
  else 
    render json: {
      status: 'ERROR',
      message: 'Slogan not saved',
      data: slogan.errors
    }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```